# Why NLog ${aspnet-request-host} is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nlog

I am running a WCF service on my desktop. I am using `${aspnet-request-host}` in `NLog.config` file. After executing the web service, I am getting the response back, but it doesn't log `host` information. I am using .NET Framework 4.

I have added

```
<extensions>
     <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
</extensions>
```

this piece to `NLog.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="C:/Users/sranade/nlog-internal.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
  </extensions>
  <!-- optional, add some variables
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->

  <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <!--
    add your targets here
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->

    <!-- database target -->
    <target name="database"
            xsi:type="Database"
            connectionStringName="NLog"
            commandText="exec dbo.InsertLog
                            @level,
                            @request,
                            @response,
                            @requesttype,
                            @retailerid,
                            @storenumber,
                            @retailerreferenceid,
                            @sourceip,
                            @transactiondate,
                            @transactiondatetime,
                            @processingtime,
                            @servername,
                            @callSite,
                            @type,
                            @message,
                            @stackTrace,
                            @innerException,
                            @additionalInfo">
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@request" layout="${event-properties:item=request}" />
      <parameter name="@response" layout="${event-properties:item=response}" />
      <parameter name="@requesttype" layout="${event-properties:item=requesttype}" />
      <parameter name="@retailerid" layout="${event-properties:item=retailerid}" />
      <parameter name="@storenumber" layout="${event-properties:item=storenumber}" />
      <parameter name="@retailerreferenceid" layout="${event-properties:item=retailerreferenceid}" />
      <parameter name="@sourceip" layout="${event-properties:item=sourceip}" />
      <parameter name="@transactiondate" layout="${event-properties:item=transactiondate}" />
      <parameter name="@transactiondatetime" layout="${event-properties:item=transactiondatetime}" />
      <parameter name="@processingtime" layout="${event-properties:item=processingtime}" />
      <parameter name="@servername" layout="${event-properties:item=servername}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@type" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${exception:format=message}" />
      <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stackTrace}" />
      <parameter name="@innerException"
                 layout="${exception:format=:innerFormat=ShortType,Message,Method:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}" />
      <parameter name="@additionalInfo" layout="${message}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger levels="Error,Warn,Fatal,Debug,Info" name="databaseLogger" writeTo="database"/>
    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: What does your NLog.Config file look like and what version of NLog?

Comment: What are the versions of NLog and NLog.web? It's using inside `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName`, not sure if that's available in WCF

Comment: @John Added ```NLog.config```

Comment: @Julian  NLog v4.4.12 and NLog.Web v4.5.0

Comment: WCF can be hosted by ASP.Net, but it doesn't have to be; even if it is, WCF doesn't go through the ASP.Net request pipeline.  How are you hosting your WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are going to be able to get the value as WCF does not run through ASP.Net.

You can try and turn it on aspNetCompatibilityEnabled but it still might not offer the value and might cause issues.